# Продолжение выполнения php-скрипта (под апачем) после отключения клиента

Tags: apache, php

Скажите, есть ли возможность сконфигурировать apache так, чтобы после того, как клиент прервал запрос, скрипт все-же завершился своим ходом, а не был жестко оборван апачем на полпути к заветной цели?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно средствами PHP. Копай в сторону *ignore_user_abort()*. И, если скрипту нужно больше времени для выполнения чем задано в настройках, то есть *set_time_limit()*.

Comment: О_о у меня почему-то все демоны работают после закрытия окна только на ini_set('max_execution_time', 0). По опыту - довольно редко, но все же может отвалиться из-за echo в отключенное соединение.

Comment: Согласен, использовать нужно крайне аккуратно, и только там, где это оправдано.

Comment: А как узнать что пользователь уже отключился?

Comment: Функция *connection_aborted()*